# Entity Framework DBFirst turns table into association, how to get table access?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a DBFirst EntityFramework 6.1 solution that i'm trying to generate off of. When i add a table that only contains two foreign keys the table is turned into two associations and I can not directly access the table anymore. This is neat for navigation in the code but makes it a pain in the ass to delete records from the table.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior and gain direct access to the table as an entity?

For example i am unable to remove an entry in the association because i get this error

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

For example here is how my database sees the structure.

[image: DBDiagram]

Here is how it appears in entity framework. Notice that the CorporateDataShareVisible table is missing and instead two new associations are created.

[image: EntityFrameworkDiagram]

The CorporateDataShareVisible table should be able to be deleted and added to at will but any changes i make seem to stop it from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a primary key to your table that has only foreign keys. EF uses the primary key to keep track internally of the element. Without a primary key it doesnt know which element was modified and how to send that back to your RDBMS.

I prefer surrogate keys i.e auto incrementing integers.
You can also add the primary key by making it a composite key of both the foreign keys